# changing numbers in position 2,4,6,8,n-2 to negatives

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I am currently stuck on this problem where I want to get all the odd number in an array adding them and turn to them to negatives and then add them to the sum of even numbers

```
 .data
    n: .word 7 # This example has 7 points
    size: .word 1 # the location in the array
    w: .word 45, 13, 46, 38, 39, 24, 33 # w0, w1, … wn-1

.text
main:
    la $9, w # get w addr
    la $13, n
    lw $13, 0($13)
    addi $20, $0,0 # i=0

loop:
    lw $16, 0($9) # $16 is the location in the array
    andi $14, $16,1 # lsb in $16 is odd or even
    bne $14, $0, odd
    add $10, $10, $16

odd:
    addiu $9, $9, 4 # array++
    addiu $20,$20,1   # i++
    sub $16, $zero, $16
    bne $20, $13, loop # goto loop if i!= size

exit:
    addi $2,$0,10    # write 10 in $v0 ($2) to call
    syscall          # syscall 10 (exit
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int sum = 0;
  int sub = 0;
  int a[7] = {12,22,32,42,52,62,72};
  for (int i = 0; i<7; i++) {
    if(i % 2 ==0){
      sum += a[i];
      cout <<sum<<endl;
    }
    else{
      sub -= a[i];
      cout <<sub<<endl;
    }
  }
  int number;
  number = (sum + sub);
  cout <<number<<endl;
}
```

no errors at the moment just stuck any help would be appreciated thanks :)

Comment: Stuck how?  `subu $t0, $zero, $t1` does `t0 = -t1`, if that's what you were missing.  Do you really need to print running totals inside the loop?

Comment: ok so basically the math should look something like 45-13+46-38+39-24+33 but I don't know how to make it do that, but if I can find all the negative numbers and add them then I can add them to the positive numbers so 163+-75 = 88

Comment: If you don't know how to loop through an array in the first place, start with that!  You have a pointer in a register; `addiu $9, $9, 4` will increment to the next element.  And you can calculate an end-pointer for `bne` as the loop condition.  Google examples on stack overflow if you need them.  And/or look at C++ compiler output, like `gcc -Og` for MIPS on https://godbolt.org/

Comment: I just want to change the number in position 2,4,6,8,...n-2 to negatives

Comment: Did you read my first comment?  That shows how to use `subu` to negate a register.  I have no idea what you're stuck *on*.  BTW, you could simplify your loop by unrolling instead of branching inside the loop.

Comment: ahhhh i see thanks :p